# How to change the default upstart log directory?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have some upstart-started apps which log a lot of stuff... I want to be able to choose in which directory the upstart logs will be saved. The default is `/var/log/upstart`.

In the [upstart docs](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/), they say I should give upstart a command-line option `--logdir`.

However, upstart is started as a daemon process by the OS as far as I know, so how can you even give it command-line arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upstart process is executed by the kernel at system boot. You can configure the command to be used by the kernel using a kernel command line argument. It should look like this:

```
init=/sbin/init --logdir=/path/to/logfiles
```

While you can configure grub to pass that command line option to the kernel, you also use a simple wrapper script for that.

Copy the original init binary to a backup:

```
sudo cp /sbin/init{,.orig}
```

Then create the wrapper script:

*/sbin/init*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Pass modified logdir option
init.orig $@ --logdir=/path/to/logfiles
```

And make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /sbin/init
```

Comment: And where do I write this from inside a virtual box??

Comment: You need to change the grub config. Which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: I would really appreciate that. uname -a prints: Linux loadapi 3.2.0-60-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 03:54:44 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please check my update. A wrapper script might be the simplest solution. Can you confirm that it is ok/working for you?

Comment: I'm on vacation now :( Will try to check this on Monday!